# Why isn't NGinX redirecting to my cached files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, nginx

I have a rails app with subomains.

I've changed the default caching location in my app so that templates are written to:

[app_dir]/public/cache/[subdomain]/[path]

So, a request to:

```
http://france.mysite.com/recipes.html
```

will write to:

```
[my_app]/public/cache/france/recipes.html
```

This is working fine, the files are being written to the correct place on the server.

My problem is that NGinx isn't serving up these cached files.

I've added the following to my NGinx config:

```
    # catch requests to www and remove the 'www'
    server {
      server_name www.mysite.com;
      rewrite ^ $scheme://mysite.com$request_uri permanent;
    }


    server {
      server_name mysite.com *.mysite.com;

      access_log /home/deploy/mysite/staging/current/log/access.log;
      error_log /home/deploy/mysite/staging/current/log/error.log;

      root   /home/deploy/mysite/staging/current/public;

      passenger_enabled on;
      rails_env staging;

      client_max_body_size 400M;
      client_body_buffer_size 128k;

        if (-f $request_filename) {
          break;
        }

        # Check / files with index.html
        if (-f $document_root/cache/$host/$uri/index.html) {
          rewrite (.*) /cache/$host/$1/index.html break;
        }

        # Check the path + .html
        if (-f $document_root/cache/$host/$uri.html) {
          rewrite (.*) /cache/$host/$1.html break;
        }

        # Check directly
        if (-f $document_root/cache/$host/$uri) {
          rewrite (.*) /cache/$host/$1 break;
        }


    }
```

Can someone point out where I've gone wrong? :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I was able to solve this issue...

the $host variable in NGinx refers to the whole host (I had mistakenly taken it as just the subdomain :/ )

Two workarounds:

a) Change the cache directory to match the full host name:
    http://france.mysite.com => /public/cache/france.mysite.com

b) Grab the subdomain from the host and use that in the if blocks instead:

```
server {
  server_name www.mysite.com;
  rewrite ^ $scheme://mysite.com$request_uri permanent;
}


server {
  server_name mysite.com *.mysite.com;

  access_log /home/deploy/mysite/staging/current/log/access.log;
  error_log /home/deploy/mysite/staging/current/log/error.log;

  root   /home/deploy/mysite/staging/current/public;

  passenger_enabled on;
  rails_env staging;

  client_max_body_size 400M;
  client_body_buffer_size 128k;

  # if the maintenance file exists, redirect all requests to it
  if (-f $document_root/system/maintenance.html) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /system/maintenance.html break;
  }

  # if the host has a subdomain, set $subdomain
  if ($host ~* "(.*)\.mysite.com"){
    set $subdomain $1;
  }

  # Rewrite index.html.
  if (-f $document_root/cache/$subdomain/$uri/index.html) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /cache/$subdomain/$uri/index.html break;
  }

  # Rewrite other *.html requests.
  if (-f $document_root/cache/$subdomain/$uri.html) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /cache/$subdomain/$uri.html break;
  }

  # Rewrite everything else.
  if (-f $document_root/cache/$subdomain/$uri) {
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /cache/$subdomain/$uri break;
  }
}
```

I went with option b) as I feel it's neater